# DateTimeField в postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-admin

Есть в модели такое поле:

```
time_created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Дата активации',
                                    unique=False, default=True)
```

Так получилось, что *migrate* отвалилось (не работает корректно), решил создать поле ручками в таблице.

После того как создал в базе, в таблице, поле *time_created* типа   *timestamp with timezone* стало ругаться в админке при попытке отобразить объект.

Подозреваю, что тип поля должен быть другой. 
Подскажите, какой... ?

Поле создавал командой:

```
ALTER TABLE public."LicControl_license" ADD time_created TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL NULL
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX LicControl_license_time_created_uindex ON public."LicControl_license" (time_created)
```

Получаю ошибку:

> ****AttributeError at /admin/Control/o/add/**
>
> **'bool' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'****

Comment: Какая именно ошибка при миграции ? Отвалится она может из-за неправильных полей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо заменить

```
time_created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Дата активации',
                                    unique=False, default=True)
```

на

```
time_created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Дата активации', default=datetime.datetime.now)
```